# how to position the label in tikz circuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

I wish to be able to put the label of the contacts above or below in order to avoid the superposition

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,positioning,chains,calc,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]

\draw (0,-1)coordinate(a0) to [make contact={info=$a_i$,name=ai}]+ (2,0) to [break contact={info=$b_i$,yscale=-1}] +(4,0)coordinate(ab);
\draw (0,-2.5) --+(2,0) to [make contact={info=$b_i$}] +(4,0) to [break contact={info=$c_i$,yscale=-1}] +(6,0) coordinate(vv)to [bulb={info=V}] +(8,0);
\draw (0,-4)coordinate(a2) to [break contact={info=$a_i$,yscale=-1,name=Nai}]+(2,0) --+ (4,0) to [make contact={info=$c_i$}] +(6,0)--(vv);

\draw[dashed] (ai) -- (Nai);

\draw (0,-0.5)node[above]{$0V$} -- (0,-4.5) ;
\draw (8,-0.5)node[above]{$12 V$} -- (8,-4.5) ;
\draw (ab)-|(vv);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the simplest way is not to inverse `break contact` switches :-)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166152/105976

Comment: @Zarko, the French electrical symbolization requires to invert the symbol (https://cours.etsmtl.ca/gpa141/autresdocuments/symboles_electriques.pdf page 2)

Comment: @sporc  I do not use circuittikz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see "TikZ \& PGF Manual for Version 3.0.1a", page 553. according to explanation there:

```
/tikz/info=[<options>]<angle>:<text>
```

you can write for example:

```
[break contact={info=below:$c_2$,yscale=-1}]
```

an example of solution for your circuit is (code is slightly simplified and improved with use of the package `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass[border=7pt,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0, 0)    to [make contact={info=$a_1$,name=ai}]  ++ (2,0) 
                to [break contact={info=below:$b_1$,yscale=-1}] ++(2,0) % <---
                -- ++ (2,0) coordinate(ab);
\draw (0,-2)    -- ++ (2,0) 
                to [make contact={info=$b_2$}] ++(2,0) 
                to [break contact={info=below:$c_2$,yscale=-1}] ++(2,0) % <---
                to [bulb={info=V}] ++ (2,0);
\draw (0,-4)    to [break contact={info=$a_3$,yscale=-1,name=Nai}] ++ (2,0) 
                -- ++ (2,0) 
                to [make contact={info=$c_3$}] ++ (2,0) 
                -- (ab);
\draw[dashed] (ai) -- (Nai);
\draw (0,0.5) node[above] {\SI{ 0}{V}} -- (0,-4.5) ;
\draw (8,0.5) node[above] {\SI{12}{V}} -- (8,-4.5) ;
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

**edit:**
the same result is available with the following shorter notation:

```
info'=<text>
```

i.e. with the following image code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0, 0)    to [make contact={info=$a_1$,name=ai}]  ++ (2,0)
                to [break contact={info'=$b_1$,yscale=-1}] ++(2,0)  % <---
                -- ++ (2,0) coordinate(ab);
\draw (0,-2)    -- ++ (2,0)
                to [make contact={info=$b_2$}] ++(2,0)
                to [break contact={info'=$c_2$,yscale=-1}] ++(2,0)  % <---
                to [bulb={info=V}] ++ (2,0);
\draw (0,-4)    to [break contact={info=$a_3$,yscale=-1,name=Nai}] ++ (2,0)
                -- ++ (2,0)
                to [make contact={info=$c_3$}] ++ (2,0)
                -- (ab);
\draw[dashed] (ai) -- (Nai);
\draw (0,0.5) node[above] {\SI{ 0}{V}} -- (0,-4.5) ;
\draw (8,0.5) node[above] {\SI{12}{V}} -- (8,-4.5) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
```